# Удалить повторяющиеся элементы в кажом столбце DataFrame'а

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Итак, есть такой DF(60x346):
[image: Исходный DataFrame]

Нужно итеративно в каждом столбце удалить дубликаты.
Я это делал так:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame()
df2=pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(1,347):
    df1=df[i].drop_duplicates()
    df2=df2.append(df1)
print(df2)
```

Но куда-то пропадают 6 столбцов и они встают не в той последовательности.
Если исходный ДФ был 60х346, то конечный выходит 346х54.
Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Вы не могли бы предоставить в воспроизводимом виде хотя бы часть исходных данных и соответствующий желаемый результат? "Лечить по фотографии" очень сложно.

Comment: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Answer (score 1):

вариант без цикла дает почти такой же результат (полные дубликаты строк тоже удаляются):

```
df2 = df.apply(lambda x: x.drop_duplicates())
```

для:

```
     brand style  rating
0  Yum Yum   cup     4.0
1  Yum Yum   cup     4.0
2  Indomie   cup     3.5
3  Indomie  pack    15.0
4  Indomie  pack     5.0
```

итог:

```
     brand style  rating
0  Yum Yum   cup     4.0
2  Indomie   NaN     3.5
3      NaN  pack    15.0
4      NaN   NaN     5.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите создать новый dataframe

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame()
for column in df1.columns:
    df2[column] = df1[column].drop_duplicates()
```